# Problems Accessing Cell Array Items Within a GUI List - Matlab

Tags: matlab, uicontrol

I have a GUI handle `list_h` that is populated using a variable named `tracks` which is a `[1xN]` cell array.  Since, each `string` within the `list_h` is assigned a value from `1:N` I have been able to devise a `for` loop that can check which item has been selected from `list_h`, which works fine.

I was hoping I could extend upon this and be able to select an item from my `list_h` and be able to extract the string using the `String` property within `list_h`, but I am getting an error:

```
Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in guiPlay (line 13)
        if i == list_value

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

I was also hoping I could get the full path to each item in `list_h`, since each item is a reference to an actual `.wav` file located on my hard drive?  I figured this would be a case of concatenating the each item with its corresponding path if this is possible?

Here is the `callback` function that attempts to extract each list item's string:

```
function guiPlay(play_toggle_h, evt, list_h)

global predict_valence

button_value = get(play_toggle_h, 'Value');
list_value = set(list_h, 'Value');
N = length(predict_valence);

if button_value == 1
    set(play_toggle_h, 'String', 'Pause');

    for i=1:N
        if i == list_value
            track = get(list_h, 'String');
            disp(track)
        end
    end

elseif button_value == 0
    set(play_toggle_h, 'String', 'Play');
end
```

Just for debugging I have used the `disp` function to display the item.

Comment: Why are you using `set` and not `get` to obtain `list_value`?

Comment: Additionally, there is no need for your nested `for` loop. You can [index cells directly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html).

Comment: I'm using `get` so I can get the string associated with the list item.

Comment: You're not using `get`, you've used `set`. The `Value` property of a listbox is the highlighted line(s). The `String` property is a cell array of strings. Use `Value` to index the strings directly. Right now you're comparing an integer `i` to nothing useful.

Comment: I see, I understand now.  As you say, just getting the `String` of `list_h` works now and retrieves the complete `[1x17]` cell array.  Would you be able to help in terms of me now retrieving a path to where each of the strings in my cell array are located on my hard drive?

Comment: How are you obtaining the strings to populate your listbox? Are they generated programmatically or are you loading data into your GUI? If it's the latter I would recommend storing the absolute paths as you're loading your data in for later access. See: [Share Data Among Callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html). If it's the former the approach is going to be dependent on how your data is organized on your drive.

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution.  I populate my initial cell array via an Excel spreadsheet to save me typing.  I could possibly store the absolute path for each song/file in Excel, then for the `list_h` I could maybe trim the string so I just get the file name displayed?